# Eclipse: automatic file opener plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm searching this feature (or plugin) in eclipse:

a prospective "project oriented" that remembers opened files, and when I open/switch another project eclipse closes all file of the last project selected and open files previously opened of the new project selected

use case:

- I select Project1 -> [eclipse closes all file actually opened]
- I double-click on file1 in Project1 -> [eclipse opens this file]
- I select Project2 -> [eclipse closes file1]
- I double-click on file2 in Project2  -> [eclipse opens this file]
- I select Project1 (again) -> [eclipse closes file2 and opens file1]

there is something like that??

thx in advance

p.s. i'm sorry for my english -.-'

Answer (score 1):

I think, the task-focused interface of Mylyn is closest to your goal. In Mylyn, you can save a context (a list of opened editors, or even positions in editors) to a task (or ticket, etc.), that can be shared.

When you want that context again, you switch to that task, and it will provide you with your old context.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Eclipse plugins at http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse.html

In particular, look at "Extended VS Presentation" and "AnyEdit".  The first one lets you manage lists of open files, and the second one includes an import/export feature for working sets.

I tried Mylyn, but I did not like it.  I want explicit control over my file sets, and Andrei's plugins provide what I want.